# JSObjects how to access to children dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I want to access a JSObject item dynamically:

```
jsonElement = {
   name:"name",
   subElement {
       subElementName: "nameSubElement",
   }
}
```

And I have the element as:

```
//level = "name"
jsonElement[level] -> it works
//level = "subElement.nameSubElement"
jsonElement[level] -> not correct. how to?
```

The important issue I can't do things like `json.subElement.nameSubElement` because I just have `var level`.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @mplungjan That is not the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key) I marked this as a duplicate of, and it is not what this question is about. Please change the duplicate question.

Comment: @mplungjan The questions are totally different. Your suggestion is about using properties in general, my suggestion answers this question: Accessing nested properties based on a *string* path.

Comment: Hmm, I think the question is far too vague to assess. So I agree that yours MIGHT answer it too.

Comment: If you read the comment to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48440218/295783 from OP, then I think mine is the one needed.

Comment: @mplungjan I read it as that OP has a *string* and using `split` only works if you know the number of properties beforehand. But anyway, OP should be more specific.

Comment: @cucuru, is the `//level = "subElement.nameSubElement"` example not supposed to be `//level = "subElement.subElementName"` ?

Comment: @mplungjan oh yes! Sorry!

Comment: @str - so my intuition was correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jsonElement.subElement.subElementName
```

or

```
jsonElement["subElement"]["subElementName"]
```

Comment: ok! I do var levels = level.split('.') and do as the second choice